# How to display the frequency count in several mysql tables in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I display the frequency of the number of students in a class. I have several tables in the database.

table = kelas

```
+----+---------+---------+
| id | tingkat | nama    |
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 |       5 | Kelas 5 |
|  2 |       3 | Kelas 3 |
+----+---------+---------+
```

table = siswa

```
+----+----------+
| id |   nama   |
+----+----------+
|  1 |        1 |
|  2 |        1 |
|  3 |        1 |
|  4 |        1 |
etc.
```

table = kelas_siswa

```
+----+----------+----------+------+
| id | id_kelas | id_siswa | ta   |
+----+----------+----------+------+
| 18 |        1 |       18 | 2019 |
| 19 |        1 |       19 | 2019 |
| 20 |        1 |       20 | 2019 |
| 21 |        1 |       21 | 2019 |
| 22 |        1 |       22 | 2019 |
| 23 |        1 |       23 | 2019 |
| 24 |        1 |       24 | 2019 |
| 25 |        1 |       25 | 2019 |
| 26 |        1 |       26 | 2019 |
| 27 |        1 |       27 | 2019 |
| 28 |        1 |       28 | 2019 |
| 29 |        1 |       29 | 2019 |
| 30 |        1 |       30 | 2019 |
| 31 |        1 |       31 | 2019 |
|  1 |        2 |        1 | 2019 |
|  2 |        2 |        2 | 2019 |
|  3 |        2 |        3 | 2019 |
|  4 |        2 |        4 | 2019 |
|  5 |        2 |        5 | 2019 |
|  6 |        2 |        6 | 2019 |
|  7 |        2 |        7 | 2019 |
|  8 |        2 |        8 | 2019 |
|  9 |        2 |        9 | 2019 |
| 10 |        2 |       10 | 2019 |
| 11 |        2 |       11 | 2019 |
| 12 |        2 |       12 | 2019 |
| 13 |        2 |       13 | 2019 |
| 14 |        2 |       14 | 2019 |
| 15 |        2 |       15 | 2019 |
| 16 |        2 |       16 | 2019 |
| 17 |        2 |       17 | 2019 |
+----+----------+----------+------+
```

How do I display data on the number of students for kelas 3 and kelas 5. on :

```
.$JUMLAH_SISWA.
```

For example Class 3 there are 17 students and Class 5 there are 14 Students

```php
public function index() {
        $d=array();
        $ambil_data_kelas = $this->db->query("SELECT id, nama FROM m_kelas ORDER BY tingkat ASC, nama ASC")->result_array();

        $tampil = "";
        if (!empty($ambil_data_kelas)) {
            foreach ($ambil_data_kelas as $v) {
                $tampil .= '<div class="col-md-4"><div class="panel panel-info">
                                <div class="panel-heading"><b>'.$v['nama'].' jumlah siswa : '.$JUMLAH_SISWA.'</b></div>
                                <div class="panel-body" style="height: 300px; overflow: auto">
                                <table class="table table-stripped">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr><th>No</th><th>Nama</th><th>Aksi</th></tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>';

                $q_siswa_per_kelas = $this->db->query("SELECT 

                                                        a.id, b.nama nmsiswa, a.id_kelas
                                                        FROM t_kelas_siswa a
                                                        INNER JOIN m_siswa b ON a.id_siswa = b.id
                                                        WHERE a.id_kelas = '".$v['id']."' 
                                                        AND a.ta = '".$this->d['ta']."'
                                                        ORDER BY b.nis ASC, b.nama ASC")->result_array();



                if (!empty($q_siswa_per_kelas)) {
                    $no = 1;
                    foreach ($q_siswa_per_kelas as $k) {
                        $tampil .= '<tr><td>'.$no++.'</td><td>'.$k['nmsiswa'].'</td><td class="ctr"><a href="#" onclick="return hapus('.$k['id'].');" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a></td></tr>';
                    }
                }

                $tampil .= '</tbody></table></div></div></div>';
            }
        }

        $this->d['tampil'] = $tampil;
        $this->d['p'] = "list";
        $this->load->view("template_utama", $this->d);
    }
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what language are these variable names in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To count the number of students in each class you only need:

```
SELECT id_kelas, COUNT(*) 'count'
FROM kelas_siswa
GROUP BY id_kelas
```

and then you can bolt on additional `JOIN`s to include whatever else you need like class metadata.

Eg:

```
SELECT ks.id_kelas, k.name, COUNT(*) 'count'
FROM kelas_siswa ks INNER JOIN kelas k
  ON ks.id_kelas = k.id
GROUP BY ks.id_kelas
```

Or getting fancy:

```
SELECT ks.id_kelas, k.name, COUNT(*) 'count', GROUP_CONCAT(s.nama) 'students'
FROM kelas_siswa ks INNER JOIN kelas k
  ON ks.id_kelas = k.id
  INNER JOIN siswa s
  ON ks.id_siswa = s.id
GROUP BY ks.id_kelas
```

Which will also list all the student names along with the count.